# Change URL for "Home" Link on D365 CE Site Map for Sales Hub Unified Interface

Tags: dynamics-crm, sitemap, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I need to replace the URL for the "Home" tab to point to the "Sales Activity Social Dashboard" in the Sales Hub D365 Unified Interface...

[image]

I can't locate this anywhere in the Site Map...

[image]

Where do I locate this at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an user personalization setting, each CRM user has to click the gear icon from the top right menu, then click the "Personalization Settings" and on the popup screen - set the "Default Pane" and "Default Tab". This will act as the "Home" for the user. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/381452/how-to-set-default-page-in-custom-model-driven-app)

> [image]

You can utilize the [XrmToolBox - User Settings Utility](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MsCrmTools.UserSettingsUtility/) to do Admin update for users in bulk.